# Oracle use defined type in package as record added to table of defined type

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following package.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE offer_actions AS
  TYPE opis_oferty_type IS RECORD (nazwa varchar(11), rocznik number(4), cena decimal(10,2), imie_klienta varchar(32), nazwisko_klienta varchar(32));
  TYPE opis_ofert_table IS TABLE OF varchar(100);
  komis_id komisy.idk%TYPE :=0;
  CURSOR c_oferty RETURN opis_oferty_type;
  FUNCTION find_oferrs(komis_id number) RETURN opis_ofert_table;
END offer_actions;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY offer_actions AS

  CURSOR c_oferty RETURN opis_oferty_type IS
    SELECT mar.nazwa, sze.rok_produkcji, ofe.cena_aktualna, kli.imie, kli.nazwisko FROM oferty ofe, szczegoly_oferty sze, modele modd, marki mar, klienci kli WHERE ofe.klient_id = kli.idk AND sze.oferta_id = ofe.idk AND ofe.model_id = modd.idk AND modd.marka_id = mar.idk AND ofe.komis_id = komis_id;

  FUNCTION find_oferrs(komis_id number) RETURN opis_ofert_table IS
    l_offers opis_ofert_table := opis_ofert_table();
  BEGIN
    FOR i in c_oferty LOOP
      l_offers.EXTEND;  
      l_offers(l_offers.COUNT) := i.nazwa;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_offers;
  END find_oferrs; 
END offer_actions;
```

When I run script I get the following error.

```
PLS-00222: no function with name 'OPIS_OFERTY_TYPE' exists in this scope
```

How can I define opis_oferty_type to allow adding new record in operation

```
l_offers(l_offers.COUNT) := (opis_oferty_type(i.nazwa,i.rocznik,i.cena,i.imie_klienta, i.nazwisko_klienta));
```

Declared types.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE opis_oferty_type AS OBJECT
(nazwa varchar(11), 
rocznik number(4), 
cena decimal(10,2), 
imie_klienta varchar(32), 
nazwisko_klienta varchar(32)
);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE opis_ofert_table AS TABLE OF opis_oferty_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a record type like an object type. It's impossible.
Object types declared only at SQL level, record types only at PL/SQL level.
Either create type `opis_oferty_type` in SQL using `create type ... as object`, or continue to use a record type, but initialize every field of a record, like that:

```
Declare
  l_v opis_oferty_type;
  ...
Begin
  ...
  l_v.nazwa:= ...;
  l_v.rocznik:= ...;
  ...
  l_offers(l_offers.COUNT) := l_v;
```

Here's a pair of links for reference: [Declaring Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adobj/declaring-initializing-objects-in-plsql.html#GUID-AA6DEB60-3D57-44CE-B0F6-D1AEC0B47AE0), [Initial Values of Record Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-AD93581B-6F16-4E84-9C05-30B251755782)

Comment: I created external object type. Command 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(offer_actions.find_offers(1));' shows me invalid data type. What can be the reason? I updated post.

Comment: You've updated your post, but it still shows that `find_offers` refers to `opis_ofert_table` declared in the package. Is it so?

Comment: Now I updated the type table  to varchar to return just simple names as collection. The error is the same. What should I change to return just table with rows as varchars.

Comment: Of course, because you cannot use PL/SQL collection in table() at SQL level

Comment: So there is no way to return table from package function ?

Comment: PL/SQL types cannot be used in SQL queries at SQL level. If you want to select from a collection returned by your PL/SQL function, the function must return the type defined at SQL level, a nested table, for example. See [the link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions)

Comment: Is it also possible for pipelined function in package?

Comment: Yes it's possible. But again I want to say that you currently have two types `opis_ofert_table`, one is in the package, another is a SQL type. Your function uses the type from the package. This is the problem.

Comment: If opis_ofert_table would be varchar(100)? Would it solve the problem?

Comment: Just remove `opis_ofert_table` declaration from the package, as well as `opis_oferty_type` and try again.